# Qt invisible combo box in release build (but not in debug build)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have an application which worked well so far. 
Today I have updated my ubuntu to 18.04 and therefore reinstalled all software components, including Qt.

Now I experience a pretty wired behavior. 
When I compile my application in debug build, everything is correct. When I switch to release build some combo boxes become invisible.

What is strange is, that events still work, the comboboxes are still there (but invisible). 
I know this because I use an `installEventFilter()`
with `if(event->type() == QEvent::Enter)` which changes some other widgets if I hover the combo box with the mouse. Although the combo boxes are invisible the events still work when I hover the area where the combo box would be located.

Unfortunately, I do not know what makes this issue, so I cannot reproduce it in a minimal example.

My question is: Did anybody experience something like this before?
And: Where should I start to look for the error? 
(I cannot debug it because everything is correct for debug builds)

By the way: I do not know if this is related but when I first tried to run the application I got an error that `gl/gl.h` was missing. After asking my friend google for help I found out that OpenGL was missing, so I installed it.

Comment: First things first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go and look for uninitalized variables when setting the properties of the combobox. Usually in debug even unitialized variables are set to some fixed value.

Or maybe you are setting properties in an assert that is not compiled in the release build? E.g. like this

```
Q_ASSERT(...)
```

that code in between the () will just be skipped during a release build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll have a look at this. What is a bit strange is that it works on windows in release, and it worked before on Linux, it just happened now when I changed to the new version in Linux

Comment: I had a look at the source code and now it workes, my `MainWindow::eventFilter` function missed a return statement (because I thought it doesn't matter). I simply added this statement and now it workes. I'll accept your answer because It gave me the right direction.